# Extract data from Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data in excel sheet in Column A in format below and want to extract it to different columns

```
                Column A
XXXXX (YYYYY (ABCDEF) 0000000000 0000000000)
XXXXX (YYYYY 0000000000)
```

Result Required

```
  A   |   B   |           C           |    D
XXXXX | YYYYY | 0000000000,0000000000 | ABCDEF
XXXXX | YYYYY | 0000000000,0000000000 |
```

Want to use one single formula for both the conditions as data cannot be sorted

Comment: @NitinJain the edits you performed and what you are now asking for is a different sequence and should be asked as a new question. [See etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions)  While it is related, the sequencing is different.  If you can copy your edited question into a new question and then roll back your edits here I would be happy to help you on the new question.  you can even link it to this one and add that it is a follow up.

Comment: The problem with changing the question is that it can invalidate the answers that have been supplied.

Comment: thanks ..will do that

Comment: @NitinJain - Mark the solution provided by ForwardEd as an answer by clicking the tick symbol on top left. Ask another question giving reference to this original question so that people can work around on the answer already provided here. Its only fair enough not to change the question when its answered just because you didn't ask completely as per your requirement.

Comment: @NitinJain - Oops! seems like you already doing it.

Comment: @NitinJain - Kindly edit this question to the old one otherwise there will be confusion of possible duplication of the question to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in B1 place

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1))
```

This formula takes the all the character to the left of the first "(".  The TRIM function removes excess space and a few other special characters.  You may or may not want to use trim.  if you do not decrease -1 to -2 or -3 etc until you have the right number of characters returned with no space at the end.

in C1

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)-FIND("(",A1)-1))
```

Little trickier and a lot of repetitiveness that makes it hard to read.  basically we find the first "(" and go 1 character to the right of that and start pulling characters.  in order to determine the number of characters to pull, the position of the second "(" was found.  this was done by finding the first "(" after the first "(".

in D1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(")",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(")",A1)-1))," ",",")
```

Same as what we did in the previous examples in terms of pulling text after finding a starting point of first ")" and the number of character we looked at the length of the string and subtracted the postion of the first ")".  Once it was down to numbers separated by a space, substitue command was used to replace the space with a coma.

in E1

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)-1)
```

This is just a really ugly repeat of what we did before just finding different start and end points to rip the text with.

You need to do the following in order to all you information back into A1.  You need to paste value or your formulas will be pointed at all the wrong things and it will generally just look really bad.

1. Select B1 to E1 and copy down as many rows as you need.
2. Select B1 to your last row in E and copy.
3. Paste right over top with paste values or paste in A1
4. Delete A1 or E1 depending where you decided to paste.

This process can be recorded in a macro if this is something you do on a regular basis.

Comment: oh thanks it worked...great for the above format but i realized  there is data in XXXXX (YYYYY 0000000000)   format in some cells as well so there it is giving error - Value .How to get  XXXXX A1 and B1 YYYYY C1 00000  (basically when there is no (abcdef) value in cell)

Comment: Well shown you above how to find various parts of the text, what you need to do is test A1 to determine if you are going to split via method A or method  B, You could check if when trying to find a second "(" if you get an error or if its a number.  Then based on that information tell it to split another way.

Comment: for further information on working with the string manipulation functions I have used I would recommend doing a google search on "Excel" and the following functions TRIM, FIND, LEN, MID, LEFT, RIGHT. SUBSTITUTE.  or even look them up in the excel help.

Comment: please see my edited question ...and if you can give the single formula to be used for both the formats ...trying to search google but not getting exactly what i want.