# Extracting data form Excel cell in different cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data in excel sheet in Column A in two formats below and want to extract it to different columns using **one single formula**

```
              Column A
XXXXX (YYYYY (ABCDEF) 0000000000 0000000000) 
XXXXX (YYYYY 0000000000)
```

Result Required

```
  A    |   B     |           C             |   D
XXXXX  |  YYYYY  |  0000000000,0000000000  |  ABCDEFA2 
XXXXX  |  YYYYY  |  0000000000             |
```

Required one formula to use for both the conditions and also c1,c2 can be 0000000000 or 000000000,00000000

This is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909923/extract-data-from-excel-cell/36910524#36910524)

Comment: Close vote retracted ([the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909923/extract-data-from-excel-cell) in question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have very structured data, AND its only two cases you are looking at, you can make do with putting your two text stripping methods inside an if statement that can figure out which case you are working with.  In this case i used:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""))>1 ,Method A, Method B)
```

The first part of the if statement counts the number of "(" there are.  If you have more than 1 use method A formula which is from your first question.  If you have 1 or fewer "(" then it will try method B formula which I added in this question.

Similar to previous answer, use the same formula in B1

in C1 change your formula to:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(",""))>1,TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,FIND("(",A2,FIND("(",A2)+1)-FIND("(",A2)-1)),LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2)),FIND(" ",A2)))
```

The new part for this question is essentially:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("(",A2)),FIND(" ",A2))
```

Its just another way you can strip off data.  I know the first formula you come to reading left to right is LEFT, but to me the formula really starts with RIGHT.  I even wrote the RIGHT formula first then went back and added the left part.  So with the RIGHT function we are basically discarding everything to the left and including the first "(".  We then take the results of the RIGHT formula and apply a left formula to it and strip off everything to the right and including the space between YYYYY 000000.

In D1 use:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""))>1,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(")",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND(")",A1)-1))," ",","),MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND("(",A2))+1,LEN(A2)-1-FIND(" ",A2,FIND("(",A2))))
```

The new part is:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND("(",A2))+1,LEN(A2)-1-FIND(" ",A2,FIND("(",A2)))
```

Basically we have done this before.  Use the MID formula to rip out text in the middle of a string.  You need to identify a starting point which I used The first space after the first "(".  While technically speaking I could have the second space.  The sentence reflects more of was is happening with the nested FIND formulas.  after finding the starting position, the number of characters to return was determined by subtracting the position of the first ")" from the over all length of the string.

in E1 use:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""))>1,MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)-1),"")
```

The new part to this equation was the easiest by far.

```
=""
```

We need that in the IF statement.  If we do not have it the cell would display FALSE as that is the value of the if statement if it is not supplied with something else for its false result.

When you have edited the formulas and put them in the right cells, used the copy paste procedure from your previous question